# Correct reasoning behind why the methodology used to evaluate limit of a sequence failed this time around - Spivak Ch.22 - 9) (iv)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, solution-verification

This question pertains to *Spivak Calculus - Ch.22 - 9) (iv)*. It has to do with why the method that I attempted to use to solve the problem actually failed in this instance. The follwowing is the introduction to these questions followed by the question:

[image]

[image]

I included part (iii) to illustrate what I did prior to question (iv).

In part (iii), I went about solving the question by first rewriting the expression into a form that would resemble an upper sum which ended up being of the form:

$$a_{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1 + \frac{k}{n})}$$

Where the term inside the summation is of the form $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x}$.

So to figure out the interval of integration I said let $P$ be an arbitrary partition $P = \{t_{0},t_{1}, \dots t_{n}\}$ and I defined $t_{k} = \frac{k}{n}$ for $k = 0,1,\dots,n$. This would then mean that $t_{0} = 0$ and $t_{n} = 1$. Thus my interval of integration is going to be over $[0,1]$. (I also think I may be doing these partitions steps in a convoluted way). So now due to the ending index of my summation being $n$, I choose to divide up the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ equal intervals which will be of length $\frac{1}{n}$. As such I can then say:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1 + \frac{k}{n})}\bigg) \approx \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x}dx$$.

So I applied this process to part (iv). Working things out, I got an expression for the sequence terms in the form of:

$$\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1 + \frac{k}{n})^{2}}$$

So again to determine a partition I took the same idea as above defining $t_{k} = \frac{k}{n}$ and arriving at my interval will be $[0,1]$ in which I will perform the anticipated integration. But first I would need to divide the interval $[0,1]$ into equal parts. Looking at the outside term of the summation I chose to divide the interval into $n^{2}$ equal parts (an unorthodox choice but what I thought would work "mechanically speaking"). Which results in subintervals of length $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$. So from this I expressed the result as:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1 + \frac{k}{n})^{2}}\bigg) \approx \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x)^{2}}dx$$.

Which can be easily evaluated by integration and you get a result of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Those that have already seen a possible mistake know I fell for the red herring as the correct result is:

[image]

Now trying to understand why the method I tried didn't work, I went back to the way I defined the partition terms as originally $t_{k} = \frac{k}{n}$ to find my interval of integration, but then afterwards chose to divide my interval $[0,1]$ into $n^{2}$ equal parts.

This is where I know the mistake happened but I can't seem to describe it properly. So if I'm dividing my interval into these $n^{2}$ equal parts, but I chose my partition to be $P = \{t_{0},t_{1}, \dots t_{n}\}$, that would mean that the last term (the $n^{\text{th}}$) term would be: $\frac{1}{n}$ and taking the limit of this would mean I end up with an interval of $[0,0]$ and as such I'm evaluating an integral at one point, i.e $$\int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{(1+x)^{2}}dx$$ which actually equals $0$.

I have a couple questions:

1. Is this the right reasoning behind why my approach to this question is incorrect?
2. I feel my methodology for finding the intervals is jumbled up and not in the right order, how should it be?
3. Is there a way of recognizing something like this happening without going through the process I did or do you need to determine the interval to see this falling apart?
4. Also it didn't feel "right" defining an interval as $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ although I don't see anything inherently wrong with being able to do it, it just feels unnecessarily complicating things.

Comment: If you chop the interval $[0,1]$ into $n^2$ subintervals, each of length $1/n^2$, we would have (for large positive integers $n$): $$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx \approx \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \frac{1}{(1 + \frac{k}{n^2})^2}$$ which is different from what you have.

Comment: I see from how you worked it out, that means I am taking an unnecessary step in trying to work out my intervals....I think. So I would have to choose how I'm going to divide up the partition into its equal parts first before I work out what my possible interval of integration is? Also what you expressed would still lead to the result I got, but the solution says the result should be $0$.

Comment: Notice that the summation I have does not relate to the  summation needed for the question.  I am showing that your attempt to relate to the integral was incorrect because you summed only over $n$ terms, not $n^2$ terms.  I am showing the correct way of using all $n^2$ terms if we wanted to relate to that integral.

Comment: Ok, I believe I understand what you're saying. Could I have switched things to sum over $n^{2}$ terms? It doesn't look feasible based on how the sequence terms were originally worked out. But maybe there is a hidden trick that would allow it.

Comment: Using subintervals of size $1/n$ gives $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} dx \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(1+k/n)^2}$ (for large $n$).  Now if you divide both sides by $n$ we see both sides approach 0 as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to relate the two objects? I ask because I wouldn't have thought about the series of inequalities given in the solution and I would've have been wracking my head to figure out how to relate the two objects. And if I did successfully relate them, then I suspect that's where I could possibly get the same solution albeit thorugh a lot more work.

Comment: What two objects are you referring to?

Comment: @Michael the integral to the upper sum.

Comment: Are you worried that I am relating to a lower sum?  If you wanted, you could relate to the upper sum by $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(1+ (k-1)/n)^2}$ (for large $n$).

Comment: @Michael No. I do understand what you're explaining. What I'm referring to is in the solution I posted the author concludes the limit equals $0$ through the inequalities : $\frac{1}{n^{2}} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} + \dots + \frac{1}{(2n)^{2}} \leq (n)(\frac{1}{n^{2}}) \leq \frac{1}{n}$. I'm saying I wouldn't have thought of that. So I'm asking if there was a way to relate the integral to the upper (or lower) sum to get the same final result as the author.

Comment: For large positive integers $n$ we have $$0 \leq \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+ ... + \frac{1}{(2n)^2} = \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(1+k/n)^2} \approx \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx $$ and the right-hand-side is $\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{(1/2)}{n}$.

Comment: @Michael, I understand now. Did you want to put this into an answer so I can mark you're explanation as the solution? You did provide me with the clarification. Thank you for you're help.

Answer (score 1):

Your error in (iv) is that  an approximate integration by dividing $[0,1]$ into $n^2$ parts should have $n^2$ terms, but you only have $n$ terms.

Let $G(n)=n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n(1+j/n)^{-2}.$ This approximates $\int_0^1(1+x)^{-2}dx=1/2$ with a partition of $n$ parts, so $G(n)\to 1/2.$ And in (iv) you want the limit of $G(n)/n.$